# Restricting access on the rails admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have the rails admin gem to see the user-friendly DB of my app. In this DB I have a lot of libraries, and I was wondering if there was a way that only certain admins could access certain libraries.
For example, admin user with email library123@admin.com can only see the details from library 123 in the rails admin DB, so this admin will only be able to access the URL
https://my-app.com/admin/library/35 and not https://my-app.com/admin/library or
https://my-app.com/admin.

I use devise for authentication to the rails admin and I do not use any gem for authorization.

I was thinking of adding a column to users with relation to the library to know which library each user belongs to, however, I am stuck thinking how would I say to the rails admin only permit to see the library this user belongs to.

Comment: How did you handle authentication? Devise ? do you use any authorization gem ?

Comment: I use devise for authentication to the rails admin and I do not use any gem for authorization.

Comment: you need to use an authorization gem as well. like CanCan, and define some custom permissions for each user.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have `#admin?` (or similar) implemented in the user model:

```
  authenticate :user, ->(user) { user.admin? } do
    # mount your restricted routes
  end
```

Comment: I do have an admin column in my user model, however, how would I be able to say user admin true with email 123@admin.com will only be able to see /admin/libraries/123 and user admin true with email 456@admin.com will only be able to see /admin/libraries/456

Comment: I see what you mean. Then yes you should consider Mohsen's answer and implement authorization, that's exactly what it is for.